# What to check after an accidental abnormal shut down on Windows 10 PC?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive

My PC was forced shut down yesterday as the circuit breaker cut out the electricity of my house. I am sure some sectors of my hard disk is corrupted as many of my software cannot load configuration file correctly and blue screen pops up while I am trying to repair the configuration files.

The situation gets better after I run a full disk scan that require restart of the computer, by typing the following in CMD:

```
chkdsk C: /f /r /x
```

C drive is my only hard drive.

However, blue screen still sometimes show up. What else should I check after such incident? (More check on Hard disk / other part of PC?)

Comment: Just download [BlueScreenViewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluescreenview.zip). Install it. Run BlueScreen Viewer. Better take snapshot of it and paste it Question. That BSOD error will help us to find the exact problem.

Comment: This! Check the system for minidump files and try to debug them with any blue screen viewers. You will then learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Not just hard disk, there are many other parameter which will popup blue screen error, mostly its due to bad RAM or hard disk. Once you get the blue screen you will see the error details too on the screen and then it will be dumped to a file. Visit this [Microsoft link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/how-to-read-dumpfiles-after-a-blue-screen-of-death/0d7522e3-4ed1-448e-bda6-66441f042c0c) to check on how to read/see the details in a dump file. or add the error details or code to the question to get exact solution of your problem.